# Is it safe to unsubscribe all events in scope.$destroy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found an AngularJS directive that looks like this:

```
function MyDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            elem.on('click', function() {
                // do stuff
            });
            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                elem.off('click');
            });
        }
    };
}
```

I'm particularly worried by the following part:

```
elem.off('click');
```

Is it safe to assume that after `scope.$destroy` the element will not be used anymore and we can simply clear **all** listeners, not only the ones this particular directive has added?

Comment: In normal situations this is safe and useless.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Not really. Added the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it depends on element for which you are unsubscribing the event. IMHO **One should always be cautious while unsubscribing the events**. I remember one my project in which I mistakenly unsubscribed `click` event which introduced subtle bugs in the project and made me feel miserable. In your case your directive is small and clean.

```
function MyDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            elem.on('click', function() {
                // do stuff
            });
            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                elem.off('click');
            });
        }
    };
}
```

so when it's scope will be destroyed, the element will not be present in the view at all and as Daan highlighted, **Listeners registered to scopes and elements are automatically cleaned up when they are destroyed** so we need not to be bothered about registered listeners cause as soon as the element will be recreated the listeners will be registered again, in your case `click` to the element. But if there are scenarios where you want to just remove the listeners you registered not all listeners then you can `namespace` your events and then subscribe and unsubscribe them:

```
//Subscribing
angular.element("#element")
  .on("click.myNamespace", function() { 
     console.log("doSomething");
   });
//Unsubscribing
$("#element").off("click.myNamespace");
```

[Here's](https://css-tricks.com/namespaced-events-jquery/) CSS trick article which talk about `namespacing` although it's based on jQuery but the concept is same.

Answer (score 2):

> **Scope Destruction** - When child scopes are no longer needed , it is the
>   responsibility of the child scope creator to destroy them via
>   scope.$destroy()API. This is done in order to stop propagation of
>   $digest calls into the child scope and allow for memory used by the
>   child scope models to be reclaimed by the garbage collector.
>
> Listeners registered to scopes and elements are automatically cleaned
>   up when they are destroyed, but if you registered a listener on a
>   service, or registered a listener on a DOM node that isn't being
>   deleted, you'll have to clean it up yourself or you risk introducing a
>   memory leak.

More information about the `angular.element`
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Scope destruction already takes care of event destruction added through the available AngularJS `directives` (example `ng-click`/ `ng-change´ / ....)

Using `ng-...` directives will do the destroyment automatically. When using custom events / listeners, always manually remove them upon the `$destroy` event.

**Yes I would state it's safe to unbind all directive (not application scoped handlers) handlers since the `scope` is destroyed anyway. Your elements belong to the scope (`ng-controller`) that is being `destroyed`, so not needed any further. In fact that is what Angular does deeper down for you anyway...**

Comment: This does not answer the specific question: is it safe to unsubscribe **all** handlers from the element, or must I explicitly unsubscribe only the ones this particular directive sets?

Comment: Allright, see the updated answer, explicitly stated :).